# Capturing and persisting electronic pad/signatures

Tags: c#, electronic-signature

I'm about to work on a project that's hopefully going to use an electronic signature pad to capture customer's signature, display texts on the device, etc etc using C#..

Now before I start doing further research, I would like to ask for some advice/suggestion from you guys which devices I should use..

My requirements as of now is quite general :  I should be able to store the image in DB, display it on the device (if possible), print/show it on the print preview (as well as in the UI)..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I don't recommend a single company, but in this case, I understand the frustration of searching for good tools.  Therefore, I'll just say that we use these: http://www.topazsystems.com/

and they have .NET support as well as Java and other languages:  http://www.topazsystems.com/Software/download/sigplusnet.htm

Finally, if you follow the last link, there are plenty of samples and documentation for you to peruse BEFORE making a buying decision.

However, there are other vendors out there.  Try googling ".NET Signature Capture"

Comment: Hi, could you give me 2 more companies/devices that you think will be feasible for this project? I just want something to compare this company with to.. :) thanks!

Comment: When I researched this and ended up using these quys, I couldn't even FIND two other companies that had .NET support, so I would go back to the google suggestion in my answer.  Topaz seems to be the "big player" for signature capture.

Comment: Ingenico progides the signature capture for our POS devices, so it's anothervoption. http://www.ingenico-us.com/signature-capture_4.html?lg=US&categoryId=16

Comment: Thank you.. Will definitely look into that :)