# Storing and verifying user signature

Tags: server-side, handwriting, electronic-signature, handwriting-recognition

I will be trying to recognize user signature, sever-side, written with a digital pen like this one. [image]

I have absolutely no experience working with a digital pad like this and the pads aren't cheap to just "try buying and see". What would be a good approach to store and verify the user signature generated by a pad like this?

1. I have found the question [Handwritten signature comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109435/handwritten-signature-comparison) but the answer provided seems to deal with recognizing handwritten letters, rather than working with a user signature.
2. [Signature Verification on OpenCV Forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/28291/signature-verification/) and [hand-written custom shapes recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784752/hand-written-custom-shapes-recognition) only suggest that this is a difficult task.

Is this an unusual task that i am trying to achieve and the pads like these are used only as a tool for storing the signature in a meaningful way in a database? If so, is it a standard to store the data as a bitmap or are signatures stored as a sequence of vectors?

If someone has any experience working with pads like these, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possibly related [Capturing and persisting electronic pad/signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998059/capturing-and-persisting-electronic-pad-signatures)